# single page navigation only touchable after scrolling

Tags: jquery, mobile, navigation

i build a single page with responsiveness for mobile devices. 
i am using a fixed position for the menü. Theres is a Menu-Button which displays an sub  after "touching" it. this works perfect. BUT after using a menu-item i have to scroll the page first before i can click the Menu-Button again.

any ideas why is that?

this on is for the toggleling of the sub-menu-div:

```
<script>
          $('#navmobile').click(function(){
             $('.submenu').toggle();
          });

</script>
```

and this one if the submenu:

```
<ul id="navmobile">
                        <li><a href="">MENÜ</a></li>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                              <li class="current"><a href="#section-1">Einleitung</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#section-2">Menüpunkt1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#section-3">Menüpunkt2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#section-4">Menüpunkt3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#section-5">Menüpunkt4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </ul>
```

and the css:

```
#navmobile {display: block !important; z-index: 100000}
    #navmobile li {float: left; list-style: none; margin: 0 18px 0 0; font-size: 26px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; -moz-margin-end: 26px}
    #navmobile li a {text-decoration: none;padding: 2px 4px;}
    #navmobile li.current a, li:hover a{color: #fff; background: #2b9ad0}
    #navmobile .submenu {display: none}
    #navmobile .submenu {width: 300px; position: absolute; left:-130px; top: 35px; background: #efefef; padding: 5px; border: 2px solid #ddd;border-radius: 1px}
    #navmobile .submenu li a{font-size: 30px; text-align: right; line-height: 60px}
```

and the css for the container around the nav:

```
    .navigation {width: 200px !important;height: 20px;position: fixed;top: 45px;left: 400px}
```

Answer (score 0):

got it myself. it was the height of the

Menü

. you have do define a larger height than normal.